# Asynchronous asymmmetric FIFO in VHDL synthesis issue

Tags: vhdl, fifo

I have designed an Asynchrounous asymmetric fifo using VHDL constructs.It is generic fifo with depth and prog_full as parameters. It has 32-bit in 16-bit output data width.
You can find the fifo design link [here](https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=65A85ABCD66EC9B3!163&authkey=!AHhqjqPJvke4Iyo).
The top level **asymmetric** fifo (fifo_wrapper.vhd),is built upon an 32-bit **asynchronous**  fifo(async_fifo.vhd). This internal fifo (async_fifo) is build using the logic from generic FIFO on open cores (http://opencores.org/project,generic_fifos). I have added a simple testbench to try out this fifo design.
BUT there is some issue with this design that I am not able to figure out. The fifo design works perfectly fine when I simulate it, but when I synthesize it and run It along with my other design on hardware I get some erroneous data sometimes. May be there is some corner case that I am not able to simulate or Is it some thing else?

That's why I would like anyone who needs this design to try it and let me know if he/she encounters any Issues during simulation or after synthesis.
thanks

PS: kindly let me know if there is some other forum where I can put my design for public use. thanks

Comment: You could host your code somewhere like github, which is free.

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of issues to point out in relation to this asynchronous FIFO
design, based on the assumption that the write and read clocks are fully
asynchronous.

- A (and probably THE) major problem is that the write side pointer (wp in
  async_fifo), which is a normal binary counter, is transfered and synchronized
  to the read side clock without any Gray encoding.  So the different bits in
  the vector may arrive at different time in the read clock domain, thus the
  write pointer value can (and most likely will from time to time) be different
  from the write side value.  The comparison with the read pointer (rp) will
  therefore make no sense.  Binary values that are transfered over clock
  domains should be Gray encoded before transfer and decoded at arrival.  Also
  use synchronization with two flip-flop levels.
- The two clocks (rd_clk and wr_clk) are assumed to be asynchronous, but there
  is only a single reset (rst), so timing may be violated when reset is
  deasserted, unless there are some additional requirements for clocking at the
  time of reset deassert.
- An similar with clear, where there is only one signal for use in two
  different clock domains.
- Suggestion would be to use a port naming convention where the clock domain
  relationship for the port is cleared indicated in the name, like naming all
  the ports in the write clock domain wr_* (e.g. wr_clk_i, wr_clk_we_i, etc.,
  and all the ports in the read clock domain as rd_*.
- Reset is asserted low, so a naming of rst_n would be nice.

Answer (score 1):

n'I can't access your code (firewall) so I'll just mention the general points in designing them, which might be of help to you and others.

- to be completely clock safe, the write side should exchange its pointer to the read side using a fully safe asynchronous handshaking method using 2 meta-stability signalling chains.

This contruct for this is a double buffered register.

1. The write side registers its write pointer into a buffer, and asserts a valid signal high.
2. A meta-stability chain reclocks the buffer valid signal to the read clock domain
3. On the read clock side, once a transition to high of valid is seen at the output of the meta chain, the data in the write side buffer is reregistered onto another register on the read domain. This is ok, because it is known that the data in the buffer is stable. (because of the meta chain).
4. The read domain asserts an ack signal high.
5. Another meta-stability chain reclocks the ack signal to the write clock domain.
6. The write side awaits a transition of the ack signal at the output of the meta chain, once seen it deasserts its valid signal.
7. The read side awaits a transition of the valid signal at the output of the meta chain to low, once seen it deasserts its ack signal.
8. The write side awaits a transition of the ack signal at the output of the meta chain to low. The cycle is now complete.
9. The current write pointer, which may have moved on quite a bit now, may now be transferred again.

A similar approach is taken for transferring the read pointer to the write domain.
It can be seen that although this approach leads to a latency between the write pointer on the write/ read side, and the read pointer on the read / write side, that this latency can never lead to overflow. Instead it leads to a premature full on the write side, adn a premature empty on the read side, which will eventually resolve once the pointers are next exchanged.

This approach is the only completely clock safe design for a fifo that doesn't depend on a-priori knowledge of the clock speeds. Gray coding is not required at all.

The other thing to note is that the logic for addressing / empty / full etc. needs to be duplicated on each  clock domain.